Incomparable area growth rate of two holomorphic functions.
Prove: There exist two holomorphic functions $f_i : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}, i = 1,2$, such that the area growth rates of both cannot be compared, namely there exist two sequences $(R_{i,j})_{j\geq 1}\nearrow +\infty, i=1,2$, such that as $j \to +\infty$:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\int_{\mathbb{D}_{R_{1,j}}} |f_1^{\prime}|^2 |dz|^2}{\int_{\mathbb{D}_{R_{1,j}}} |f_2^{\prime}|^2 |dz|^2} \to +\infty,
\frac{\int_{\mathbb{D}_{R_{2,j}}} |f_2^{\prime}|^2 |dz|^2}{\int_{\mathbb{D}_{R_{2,j}}} |f_1^{\prime}|^2 |dz|^2} \to +\infty.
\end{equation}
where $\mathbb{D}_r := \{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| < r\}, r > 0.$
I think that there might be two helpful lemma:
Lemma 1 : Let $z_0 \in \partial \mathbb{D}_R$ ($R > 0$), let $U$ be a small neighborhood around $z_0$. Then we can find a holomorphic function $\chi: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}_R \setminus U$, $|\chi| < 1$ and $|\chi(z_0)| > 1$.
(I think that Riemann Mapping Theorem and Runge's Approximation Theorem can be useful. Directly constructing a specific function is too much difficult.)
Lemma 2 : Define $R_{i,j} := i+2j, z_{i,j} := i+2j$. Use induction to construct
\begin{equation}
F_{i,0} := 0, \quad F_{i,j} := F_{i,j-1} + \chi_{i,j}^{M_{i,j}} \quad (i=1,2; j \geq 1),
\end{equation}
where $\chi_{i,j}$ is for $z_{i,j} \in \partial \mathbb{D}_{R_{i,j}}$ obtained by using Lemma 1. Choose $M_{i,j} \gg 1$ , such that
\begin{equation}
\frac{\int_{\mathbb{D}_{R_{i,j}}} |f_i^{\prime}|^2 |dz|^2}{\int_{\mathbb{D}_{R_{i,j}}} |f_{3-i}^{\prime}|^2 |dz|^2} \gg 1.
\end{equation}
Define $f_i = \lim_{j \to +\infty} F_{i,j}$. The existence of $f_i$ is equal to the existence of $\chi_{i,j}$ and $M_{i,j}$.
So the problem is, how to choose $\chi_{i,j}$(Prove Lemma 1) and $M_{i,j}$(Prove Lemma 2)?
(Both constructive and non-constructive methods are permitted.)

I can give a fairly easy direct solution to the original problem above (about the ratios of integrals) without going through the lemmas if you have interest in that

@Conrad I do have interest in your method. Maybe my lemma make the question more complicated. Your easy direct solution is always welcomed: )

Note that if $f(z)=\sum a_n z^n$ is entire, then using polar coordinates we get $$\int_{\mathbb{D}_R}|f^{\prime}|^2 |dz|^2=\pi\sum_n n|a_n|^2R^{2n}$$ so we need to find coefficients (of entire functions) $a_n,b_n$ and radiuses $R_k, \tilde R_k$ st the corresponding ratios go to infinity.
For simplicity we pick both $a_n, b_n$ to be either $1/n!$ or $0$ (so they are coefficients of entire functions) as follows. Let $n_1=2, m_1=n_1^{n_1}=4$ and inductively $n_k=m_{k-1}^{m_{k-1}}, m_k=n_k^{n_k}, k \ge 2$ and $a_n=1/n!, n=m_k, b_n=1/n!, n=n_k$ and zero otherwise and we pick $R_k=m_k, \tilde R_k=n_k$ and we need to show that $$\frac{\sum_n n|a_n|^2R_k^{2n}}{\sum_n n|b_n|^2R_k^{2n}} \to \infty, k \to \infty$$ and the reverse for $\tilde R_k$. By the symmetry of our choices it is enough to prove the first.
We first use that the numerator is at least the $n=m_k$ term which is $\frac{m_k m_k^{2m_k}}{m_k!^2}>e^{2m_k}$ by Stirling and then we use that for the denominator we can majorize each of the nonzero terms up to $n_k$ (which are $k<n_k$ by $n_km_k^{2n_k}$ (ignoring the $1/n! \ge 1$) so get a total of $n_k^2m_k^{2n_k}$ while the (nonzero) terms after $n_k$ which start at $n \ge n_{k+1}= m_k^{m_k}$ are obviously very small eg at most $1/n^2$ since $\frac{n m^{2n}}{(n!)^2} \le 1/n^2, n \ge m^m, m \ge 10$ say by Stirling again, so they all sum to at most $1$ say.
So putting it all together we get that $$\frac{\sum_n|a_n|^2R_k^{2n}}{\sum_n|b_n|^2R_k^{2n}} \ge \frac{e^{2m_k}}{n_k^2m_k^{2n_k+1}+1}, m_k=n_k^{n_k}$$
Taking logarithms the ratio is bigger than $2n_k^{n_k}-4n_k\log (n_k^{n_k})=2n_k^{n_k}-4n_k^2\log n_k \to \infty, k \to \infty$ so we are done!
